# How to update directive using data from service?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I have a service MyService that has a property "data" that contains contents retrieved from 2 or 3 $http requests and stores it into "data". This "data" needs to be accessible or passed to a directive to process, (like a modal).

The service "MyService" contains an attribute "data" necessary for myDirective to process on first load.

```
// var app = angular.module...
app.service('MyService',...)
```

I have a separate directive "myDirective":

```
var myDirective = angular.module('myDirective', []);
myDirective.directive('control', ['Params', function(Params) {...
```

I tried to inject "MyService" by doing the following:

```
var myDirective = angular.module('myDirective', ['MyService']);
myDirective.directive('control', ['Params', function(Params) {...
```

Though it fails to instantiate saying:

```
error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyService' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

How do I properly instantiate my myDirective from myService? Is this the right approach or should I be using some controller/factory/provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating `myService` as a  module which it is not, it is a component of a module. You only inject modules into other modules. Once all dependent modules are injected into main module, components of all modules are directly available to other components, regardless of which module they are initially registered to.

To inject into a directive you do it the same way you are injecting `Params` into directive. I suspect you are needlessly creating a new module just to create a directive.

Try this way:

```
app.service('MyService',...);
app.directive('control', ['Params','MySerrvice', function(Params,MyService) {...
```

Now within the directive you have access to objects in service using `MyService.propertyName`

Comment: The directive was created by someone else in its own "directivesOwnApp" and I had injected it into the module of the main app = angular.module['app'], ['<insert-directive-module-here>']). .. Though it seems it can't see myService.

Comment: ok...but code you've shown is trying to inject `MyService` as a module still. Assuming `var app` is a module, the service is already being registered as a component of that module. No matter what you also need to inject the service into directive also if you want to access it from inside directive

Comment: For the keeping the current modularity, and allowing the directive to stay within its own directivesOwnApp (angular.module..) (without renaming it to "app"), is there a way to pass the information from the service to it and/or information from the directive back to the service? (note that 'control' is one of multiple directives in the directivesOwnApp". Or is it not possible and I have to fold the directive into my own "app" to access the service?

Comment: can be in different module as long as that module is injected in main page module the service can be injected anywhere. Can you, or can you not inject the service in directive as with `Params`?

Comment: BTW... modulrity of combining `directives` into a directive module and `services` to a services module may sound good on paper. But realistically modules are better grouped by functionality if ever want to use them elsewhere

Comment: Here's a proof of concept demo showing service in one module injected into controller registered in different module http://plnkr.co/edit/DdPVgNs6njxQPpI6ZIN0

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is adding `MyService` service as a **module** to your `MyDirective` module which won't work.

The easy way would be to just add the directive to your app module and inject your service:

```
app.directive('control', ['Params', 'MyService', function(Params, MyService) {
   //...
}]);
```

If you create extra modules for your directives and and maybe also for your services you will have to add these modules to your app module like for example (usually in app.js):

```
var directivesModule = angular.module('app.directives', []);
var servicesModule = angular.module('app.services', []);

var app = angular.module('app', ['app.directives', 'app.services']);
```

And then add your services and directives to the respective modules:

```
servicesModule.service('MyService',...);

directivesModule.directive('control', ['Params','MyService', function(Params, MyService) {
    //...
}]);
```

Create one file per service/directive or a file for all services and one for all directives. Depends on the size of your app.

Comment: The directive myDirective is in its own module that I added to my own app module. Though I am not sure how to get the information from my service (in app) into the myDirective (of its own module) for the sake of keeping its existing modularity.